# jQuery Validation Plugin not working properly with remote rules (latest jquery and latest plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need some help with jquery validation plugin for remote rules. The form seems to get submitted even when inputs are invalid. The validation works ok when I submit the form for the first time, but if I click the button again, the form get submitted with invalid inputs.

any ideas? thanks

```
<html lang="en">
 <head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>test</title></head>
  <body>
     <form id="validate" method="post" action="?go=submit">
      <input type="text" placeholder="test 1" id="test1" name="test1" value="test@test.com" class="required email">
      <br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="test 2" id="test2" name="test2" value="" class="required" minlength="5">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#validate").validate();
    $("#validate").removeAttr("novalidate");
    if($('#test1').length)  {$("#test1").rules("add", {remote: "/test1", messages: {remote: "test 1 failed."}});}
    if($('#test2').length) {$("#test2").rules("add", {remote: "/test2", messages: {remote: "test 2 failed."}});}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you see in developer tools whether the AJAX calls are happening?

Comment: Can you help us understand how you are submitting this form more than once without doing a form reset?  Are you talking about a successful submission or simply clicking the button?

Comment: Also, why are you removing the `novalidate` attribute?  This is automatically added by the plugin for a reason and it should not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing above problem. I replaced my JQuery file "jquery-1.4.1.js" with new "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" and my problem solved. Try may be it help you.